# Regular Expression Matching Issue (using R)

Tags: r, regex

I have string vectors with a product name followed 6 numbers corresponding to 6 different columns of data.

I want to be able to extract the product name or the 6 final numbers (which can then be split as they are always separated by a whitespace). The final 6 numbers always have a dot in the middle.

I have tested a regex expression (below) which can extract 6 numbers in succession from the string, however, it fails when the product name also has a number in it (e.g. example 1 below has "£2.00" in its name).

I need to change this so it can begin the search at the end of the string so only the last 6 numbers are selected.

Current Regular Expression:

```
([\d]+[.][\d]+[\s]?){6}
```

Example strings:

```
  [1] "white coffee tall £2.00 6.00 6.00 6.00 0.00 1.00 5.00"                         
  [2] "product group:0 Total 6.00 6.00 6.00 0.00 1.00 5.00"                      
  [3] "£1.45 CAKE 12.00 17.40 17.40 0.00 2.90 14.50"                             
  [4] "95P CAKE £5.00 32.00 30.40 30.40 0.00 5.07 25.33"                               
  [5] "Complementary hot beverage 11.00 0.00 0.00 0.00 0.00 0.00"                
  [6] "Flat white Large 5.00 5.00 5.00 0.00 0.83 4.17"                           
  [7] "Flat white Small 8.00 5.20 5.20 0.00 0.87 4.33"                           
  [8] "Go ahead Bar 5.00 4.25 4.25 0.00 0.71 3.54"                               
  [9] "Graze Box 2.00 3.20 3.20 0.00 0.00 3.20"                                  
 [10] "Joe & Seph popcorn 2.00 1.90 1.90 0.00 0.32 1.58"                         
 [11] "Kit kat 4 finger 6.00 3.00 3.00 0.00 0.50 2.50"
```

String to extract (first two examples):

```
[1] "6.00 6.00 6.00 0.00 1.00 5.00"   
[2] "6.00 6.00 6.00 0.00 1.00 5.00"
```

Comment: Try `sub(".*((?:\\b\\d+[.]\\d+\\s*){6}).*", "\\1", x)` (maybe the last `.*` is not even that important and can be replaced with `$`). See https://regex101.com/r/PXmGu1/1

Comment: Thanks, I'll try to get my head around what its doing in a regex tester, not very experienced with it (although it seems to work).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**1)** It seems you want the last 6 fields of the input character vector `s` pasted together:

```
sapply(strsplit(s, " "), function(x) paste(tail(x, 6), collapse = " "))
```

**2)** Also note that a minor tweak to the regular expression in the question works.

```
sub(".*(([\\d]+[.][\\d]+[\\s]?){6})$", "\\1", s, perl = TRUE)
```

**Note:** The input `s` in reproducible form is:

```
s <- c("white coffee tall £2.00 6.00 6.00 6.00 0.00 1.00 5.00",
"product group:0 Total 6.00 6.00 6.00 0.00 1.00 5.00",                 
"£1.45 CAKE 12.00 17.40 17.40 0.00 2.90 14.50",                             
"95P CAKE £5.00 32.00 30.40 30.40 0.00 5.07 25.33",                               
"Complementary hot beverage 11.00 0.00 0.00 0.00 0.00 0.00",
"Flat white Large 5.00 5.00 5.00 0.00 0.83 4.17",                 
"Flat white Small 8.00 5.20 5.20 0.00 0.87 4.33",                          
"Go ahead Bar 5.00 4.25 4.25 0.00 0.71 3.54",                          
"Graze Box 2.00 3.20 3.20 0.00 0.00 3.20",                              
"Joe & Seph popcorn 2.00 1.90 1.90 0.00 0.32 1.58",
"Kit kat 4 finger 6.00 3.00 3.00 0.00 0.50 2.50")
```

Comment: Ah, this would be a simpler solution! Don't know why i didn't think of this, not sure if it's preferable to a regex solution at the moment but easier for me to understand for sure.

Comment: You do not need to use `perl=TRUE` if you take out shorthand character classes out of the square brackets.

Comment: I wanted to make minimal changes to the regex in the question but good point.